# SQL: UNION on table with different number of children each parent

Tags: sql, union, common-table-expression

The problem it seems is that I can't use the current method because every parent has a varying number of children, but I can't seem to find another method. Does someone have any ideas?

```
id  Name  parentId
1   Collecting  -1
30  Other classic toys  19016
32  Dolls   1
34  Art 1
35  Paintings   34
38  Other Coca Cola 62848
57  Movie objects   196
63  Comic books 267
64  Other comics    900
```

> All queries combined using a UNION, INTERSECT or EXCEPT operator must
>   have an equal number of expressions in their target lists.

I have tried:

```
with testtable as (
    select  *
    from    Categories c
    where   c.parentId = -1

    union all

    select  *
    from    Categories cc
    inner join  testtable tt
    on      tt.id = rr.parentId
)
select * from testtable
```

The columns are 'id', 'name' and 'parentId'.

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: Your question is database-specific. Base on which `RDBMS` you are using, it may be complete by using `recursive-CTE` or `Hierarchical Query`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `select *`, write out the column names `select id, name, parentId`

In reply to your comment, you can sort children below parents like:

```
with testtable as (
    select  id, name, parentId, id as root
    from    Categories c
    where   c.parentId = -1

    union all

    select  id, name, parentId, root
    from    Categories cc
    inner join  testtable tt
    on      tt.id = rr.parentId
)
select * from testtable order by root, parentId
```

This stores the parent in the `root` column.  Parents will be sorted above children because their `parentId` is `-1`.

Comment: Thanks! It worked. Is it possible to put the parent before every couple children in the result?

Comment: Sure, you can pass the outmost parent along in the recursion. Updated in answer.

Comment: What if i wanted to show all children directly underneath the previous parent?

Comment: You could build a sortable path, like '000001/000015/...`  How to do that depends on which database you are using (SQL Server, Postgres, Oracle...)

Answer (score 0):

You need to same amount of columns in both selects so for example:

Table A:

```
create table TableA (
A varchar(255),
B varchar(255),
C varchar(255),
D varchar(255)
)
```

Table B:

```
create table TableB (
A varchar(255),
B varchar(255),
C varchar(255)
)
```

You could not do:

```
with unionselect do(
select * from TableA
union all
select * from TableB
)
```

Because Table A has 4 Columns and Table B has only 3

What you could to instead is fill up with "null" for example:

```
with unionselect do(
select a.A, a.B, a.C, a.D from TableA a
union all
select b.A, b.B, b.C, null from TableB b
)
```

So in your case, because you are joining with "testtable" that may result in your bottom select to return more columns than the first select

Best Regards